# Do I need to hash refresh token stored in database?

Tags: database, go, hash, jwt

I am working on a web application that is using `Go` in the backend and JWT based authentication. When users logged in, I send them access token with a short expiration time and a refresh token with a long expiration time. Both of these tokes includes `username` as their payload. They are created with different secrets. My question is about log out. When a user sends a log out request, I want to invalidate it's refresh token so that they are needed to log in again after log out. For solution, I am going to store that refresh token in a blacklist table in my database. My question is that should I need to hash that refresh token before storing it in the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the standard JWT claims ([RFC 7519 §4.1.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7)) is `"jti"`, which is a unique identifier for the token.  If you include a unique identifier in your refresh token, then it's enough to store the `"jti"` and `"exp"` (expiration) claims in the database.  (I'd default to using [`("github.com/satori/go.uuid").NewV4`](https://godoc.org/github.com/satori/go.uuid#NewV4) to generate the `"jti"` as a random UUID, and that's internally backed by the `"crypto/rand"` random-number generator.)

Now if you're presented a refresh token, you can do your usual checks that it's correctly signed and unexpired, and then look up the `"jti"` in the database.  If it's not on the blacklist, then it's good for reuse.  You only need to keep `"exp"` in the database to know when it's safe to clean records out.  Since the `"jti"` is just a random identifier, you can't get back from the `"jti"` to any identifiable information so there's no particular need to hash or encrypt it.

If you don't have a `"jti"` and can't add one, I'd probably either hash the token or just keep a copy of the claims.  Partly this is for space reasons, and partly you don't want to store something that's actually a valid credential.  Keep enough information that you can uniquely identify a token; possibly the `"sub"` and `"exp"` time together are enough information (if two tokens issued to the same subject expiring at the same second are indistinguishable).

Comment: That really makes sense to store `jit` inside the refresh token JWT. Thanks.

Comment: If the JWT payload contains an expiry, and that exp value was signed by a valid authority... why do you need to store the expiry in the db?

Comment: If i could answer my own question... It's possibly to limit the number of valid refresh tokens to 1. If someone generates 1k refresh tokens for a single app... its not possible to invalidate just one of them... you would need to invalidate all of them, and in the case of a compromise you can not be surgical in your response. its nukes or nothin'. That means you need to BREAK a legit app, and force it to re-login all it's users because of one refresh token in the hands of an attacker.

Comment: @Pandem1c In which scenarios can that happen?

Comment: Are you asking "In which scenarios can someone compromise a refresh token?" Im not sure what you're asking @Johnnyboy